# unable to start workflow in Alfresco share 4.2

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I deleted the existing process and renamed the id to a custom id MyActivitiParallelReview. Redeployed this process through activiti admin console. I defined the below config in share-config-custom.xml.

```
     <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$MyActivitiParallelReview">
      <forms>
     <form>
        <field-visibility>
           <show id="bpm:workflowDescription" />
           <show id="bpm:workflowDueDate" />
           <show id="bpm:workflowPriority" />
           <show id="bpm:assignees" />
           <show id="wf:requiredApprovePercent" />
           <show id="packageItems" />
           <show id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
           <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.general" />
           <set id="info" appearance="" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-                column-set.ftl" />
           <set id="assignee" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.assignees" />
           <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />
           <set id="other" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.other" />

           <field id="bpm:workflowDescription" label-id="workflow.field.message">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                 <control-param name="style">width: 95%</control-param>
              </control>
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:workflowDueDate" label-id="workflow.field.due" set="info">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/date.ftl">
                  <control-param name="showTime">false</control-param>
                  <control-param name="submitTime">false</control-param>
              </control>
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:workflowPriority" label-id="workflow.field.priority"        set="info">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/priority.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="wf:requiredApprovePercent" label-id="workflow.field.requiredApprovePercent" set="assignee">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/percentage-approve.ftl">
                 <control-param name="minValue">1</control-param>
                 <control-param name="maxValue">100</control-param>
              </control>
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:assignees" label-id="workflow.field.reviewers" set="assignee"    />
              <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
              <field id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" set="other">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/email-    notification.ftl" />
                </field>
            </appearance>
           </form>
          </forms>
        </config>
```

However when I start the workflow from share I am seeing error 10300034 Failed to start workflow activiti$MyActivitiParallelReview:1:1959

Please assist me what might be the issue ?

Comment: put some debugging on the workflow and post it here.

Comment: thank you for the giving the clues. Got it working, when I renamed the id, I forgot to rename the digarm element with the new id. I corrected it.        <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="MyActivitiParallelReview" id="BPMNPlane_activitiParallelGroupReview">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, when I renamed the id, I forgot to rename the digarm element with the new id. I corrected it.